# Good or Bad Practice: using static map variable in Spring Boot Kafka Listener

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Is it a good practice to use static maps in variables in a Spring Boot Kafka Listener?

here is an example of such code:

```
private static Map<String, SomeModel> someMap = new HashMap<>();

...
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topics}", groupId = "${kafka.group_id}")
public void consume(String message) {
    ...
    if (someMap.get(entity.getNumber()) == null) {
        someMap.put(entity.getNumber(), new SomeModel());
    }
    ...
    SomeModelmodel = someMap.get(dmr.getNumber());
    someMethod();
}

private void someMethod() {
    // Access some Map
    SomeModelmodel model = someMap.get(dmr.getNumber());
    // Do something with model
    model.setTemp(-2);
}
```

Should the static variable not be at least `volatile` to avoid memory visibility problems like the ones described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-volatile)?

Or is the usage of mutable `static` variable simply something that is just an anti-pattern to avoid in these types of listeners, even if the listener is single threaded?

Comment: It can cause concurrency issues if multiple instances of the listener are running concurrently.

Comment: @SaifAhmad yes, I agree.